# use echo or Die for debugging and logging

Tags: php, apache, logging, echo, die

The questions says everything. I am logging something on STDOUT.Should I use echo for displaying or `Die()`.As far as I know If I use die() for normal printing like `die('Entered in For loop')`, it exits the program.
Also is it good to log to files or mysql?

Comment: It's always a good idea to log when a program encounters an unexpected error. That way you can learn from it and hopefully prevent it from happening again in the future.

Comment: `file_put_contents("someapp.log", "LOG EVENT\n", FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: `die()` output is going to get sent to the client. Generally speaking, you don't want debug information sent to the client because it can reveal internal details of your system. for users you say "Oops, something blew up". For internal logging, you'd include vastly more detail to help track down the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For debugging I prefer `var_dump()`. If you install Xdebug (http://xdebug.org/) in your development environment, you'll get a lot more out of var_dump.

When I want to kill a script I'm debugging, I wrap die around that, as in `die(var_dump())`.

For logging, look into PHP's `error_log()` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) function or a logging library such as monolog (https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog).

Answer (score 0):

```
function dd($obj) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $n = count($args);
    for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        error_log(print_r($args[$i], true));
    }
}
```